# Unable to understand the code

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying to make a code to find duplicates in an array and print them. I can't understand this code and why the Calloc is being used and the int main part isn't clear to me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
  int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), (size - 2));
  int i;

  printf(" Repeating elements are ");
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {  
    if(count[arr[i]] == 1)
      printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
    else
     count[arr[i]]++;
  }    
}     

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1};
  int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  
  printRepeating(arr, arr_size);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You wrote a code that you do not understand? :-)

Comment: ^^^ that and.... what malloc?

Comment: Would be safer to use max(arr) instead of `size-2` as count parameter in the `calloc` call. Just sayin'.

Comment: @iCas   I also do not understand why you are using the dynamic array.:)

Comment: Perhaps as a supposition This is considering the possibility of using a working array of unavailable length on the stack. By the way VLA can not be used as static.

Comment: Yeah, mebbe no VLA in OP's C ?

Comment: Also, calloc() but no free().  Prolly. does not matter much in this program, but....

Comment: ..and what's with the '(size - 2)' ??

Comment: @ThingyWotsit It's used as a count parameter

Comment: Not only do you index `count` by a number in the range of `int`, but you never build that array in the first place. It is doomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is really wrong, you shouldn't use it at all.

To give you some hints, this line creates an array:

```
int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), (size - 2));
```

Similar to:

```
int count[size - 2] // If size was a constant
```

An unfortunate issue is that the function never disposes the dynamically created array, so you'll see a memory leak.

Line `count[arr[i]]++` is a disaster: if the value of `arr[i]` is greater than `size-2` then the software will write to an unassigned memory.

To show how it should be done:

```
// No value should exceed 50
#define MAX_ARR 50

void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
    int found[MAX_ARR];
    int i;

    // Set found variable to 0
    memset(found, 0, sizeof(found));

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {  
        // Did we find the same number before?
        if (found[arr[i]] == 1) {
            // Yes, print it
            printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
        } else {
            // No, mark is as found
            found[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: No wonder I could not understand it - it was too bad for me to work out what was going on:(

Answer (score 4):

The code is actually "dangerous", as it relies on some conditions to hold, e.g. that the maximum integer value in the array is not larger than `size-2`. So, if your input were, for example, `int arr[] = { 114, 112, 114, 5, 2, 3, 1}`, then `arr[0]` would be `114`, and the code `count[arr[0]]++` would exceed the bounds of the array allocated in `printRepeating`, which were just 5 elements.

I'd throw the code away and write your own; almost regardless on your experience, your code is likely not worse than the proposed one :-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for using `calloc` is that the size isn't known in advance. An alternative would be to use VLA but apparently the author preferred dynamic memory allocation. Kind of bad as the author forgot to `free` the memory. So this code leaks memory.

Besides that the code is very error prone as it relies on some specific rules for the input (e.g. that no input value is greater that `size-2`). So my advice is to through this code away and start all over.

BTW: The code uses `calloc` instead of `malloc` to get the memory zero initialized.

Regarding `main`.... This line:

```
int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

calculates the number of elements in the array.

```
sizeof(arr) is likely to return 28

sizeof(arr[0]) is likely to return 4
```

So

```
28/4 = 7 which is the number of array elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually we use `malloc( )` for allocating a single block of specified size that returns a pointer of type of void. This means that we can assign it to any type of type. Form is:
    `ptr = ( cast - type*) malloc(byte-size)`

One very significant difference in `malloc()` and `calloc()` is :
While `malloc()` allocates a single block of storage space with garbage (or random) values,  `calloc()` allocates allocates multiple blocks of storage, each of the same size, and then sets all bytes to zero.

Comment: `calloc` does not allocate multiple blocks of storage. The pointer returned is to a single contiguous block of memory, and the function does the multiplication of the arguments `size_t num` and `size_t size` for you.